# Spring Schedule method being called twice

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, spring-mvc

I already read all the questions about methods being called twice on Spring but I just can't resolve this problem.

I'm using the annotation `@Scheduled` to run a task from time to time.

```
@Scheduled(fixedDelay = 60000)
    public void getTickets() {
```

Tomcat run the WebApplicationContext

```
.16:33:00.598 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  o.s.web.context.ContextLoader - Root WebApplicationContext: initialization started 
.16:33:00.752 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  o.s.w.c.s.XmlWebApplicationContext - Refreshing Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Fri Jul 11 16:33:00 BRT 2014]; root of context hierarchy 
.16:33:00.835 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  o.s.b.f.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader - Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]     ...
```

and the servlet context.

```
.16:33:01.614 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - FrameworkServlet 'my-context': initialization started 
.16:33:01.620 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  o.s.w.c.s.XmlWebApplicationContext - Refreshing WebApplicationContext for namespace 'my-context-servlet': startup date [Fri Jul 11 16:33:01 BRT 2014]; parent: Root WebApplicationContext 
.16:33:01.621 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  o.s.b.f.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader - Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/my-context-servlet.xml]
```

And then my method is called twice.

I think in two alternatives:

**1 - Remove the Root WebApplicationContext.**

Is it possible? When I remove that piece of code:

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

I just can't get anything from my web application.

```
GRAVE: Servlet.service() for servlet [my-context] in context with path [] threw exception java.lang.IllegalStateException: No WebApplicationContext found: no ContextLoaderListener registered?
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:252)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
```

**2 - "Filter" the class out from root context**

It is possible to do such thing?

Here is my full web.xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    version="2.5">
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>my-context</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>my-context</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <!-- Spring Security -->
    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy
        </filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
</web-app>
```

I appreciate any help to resolve this issue.

Thanks.

Comment: Probably the bean is instantiated twice. For example if you declare it in the context(xml or java) and you have component scan and @Component annotation on the class.

Answer (score 4):

@Evgeni is likely right, your bean is being instantiated twice.

Here is what works for me. Note in this setup it's important to put your scheduled annotation somewhere that isn't called from dispatcher-servlet.xml.  For maintainability I keep all my scheduled routines under *.utilities.scheduledRoutines.

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

    <!-- Creates the Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>net.xyz.ncc.utilities.ShutdownListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <context-param>
       <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
       <param-value>classpath:spring/security-config.xml,classpath:spring/app-config.xml,/WEB-INF/spring/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- Handles all requests into the application -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Spring MVC Dispatcher Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>
                /WEB-INF/spring/dispatcher-servlet.xml
            </param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>  

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Spring MVC Dispatcher Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <!--  Spring Security -->
    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping> 

</web-app>
```

**dispatcher-servlet.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd">    

    <context:component-scan base-package="net.xyz.ncc.controller" />

    <!-- Configures support for @Controllers -->
    <mvc:annotation-driven />

    <!-- Resolves view names to protected .jsp resources within the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/"/>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

**servlet-context.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="net.xyz.ncc" />

    <task:annotation-driven executor="taskExecutor" scheduler="taskScheduler" />
    <task:executor id="taskExecutor" pool-size="1"  /> 
    <task:scheduler id="taskScheduler" pool-size="1"  />


</beans>
```

Comment: Excellent answer and exhibits, I spent half a day before I found this

Comment: How to resolve in Spring boot, My config is anotation based